# create appointment app with django with non register user

Tags: django

I'm trying to create an appointment app with Django for register and non register user

in the case of register user it's easy

but for non register user my idea is to create a temporary user with just a few information in the user form and the profile form

but it showed me nothing in the html file and in the first case it did not save the appointment

this is my function in the views.py

```
@login_required
def create_appointment_D(request):
    if request.method=='POST' :
        user = User()
        if request.user.is_doctor() or request.user.is_reception():
            appointment = request.POST['type']
            if appointment=='register patient':
                form_appointment = AppointmentForm_2()
                if form_appointment.is_valid():
                    form_appointment.save(commit=False)
                    form_appointment.user = request.user
                    form_appointment.end_time = form_appointment.start_time + timedelta(minutes=30)
                    form_appointment.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'appointment added')
                else:
                    messages.error(request, 'Error')
                    
                
            else:
                form_appointment = AppointmentForm_2() 
                form_user = UserEditForm() 
                profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm()
                if form_appointment.is_valid() and form_user.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                    form_appointment.save(commit=False)
                    form_appointment.user = request.user
                    form_appointment.end_time = form_appointment.start_time + timedelta(minutes=30)

                    form_user.save(commit=False)
                    form_user.type_of_user = user.type_of_user.TEMPORARY

                    profile_form.save(commit=False)

                    form_appointment.save()
                    form_user.save()
                    profile_form.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'appointment added')
                else:
                    messages.error(request, 'Error')
            return render(request, 'appointement/add_appointement1.html', {'form':form_appointment, 'user_form':form_user, 'form_appointment': profile_form})
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("create_appointment_P"))

    return render(request,'appointement/add_appointement_options.html')
```

this is my forms.py

```
class AppointmentForm_2(forms.ModelForm):
    doctor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(type_of_user=TypeOfUser.DOCTOR))
    patient = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(type_of_user=TypeOfUser.PATIENT))
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    start_time = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('patient', 'doctor', 'date', 'start_time')

class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('date_of_birth', 'gender', 'phone_number', 'blood_group', 'address', 'photo')
```

and this is my models.py

```
class TypeOfUser(models.TextChoices):
    PATIENT = 'patient', 'Patient'
    DOCTOR = 'doctor', 'Doctor'
    RECEPTION = 'reception', 'Reception'
    TEMPORARY = 'temporary', 'Temporary'

class User(AbstractUser):
    type_of_user = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=TypeOfUser.choices, default=TypeOfUser.PATIENT)
    allowd_to_take_appointement = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=AllowdToTakeAppointement.choices, default=AllowdToTakeAppointement.YES)

    def is_doctor(self):
        return self.type_of_user == TypeOfUser.DOCTOR


    def is_temporary(self):
        return self.type_of_user == TypeOfUser.TEMPORARY
```

how can I in the 2nd case create a new user with the type of user = TOMPORARY?

Answer (score 1):

if you use `@login_required` the page is accessible only by authenticated users with django accounts.

Remove it before `def` and create your view but in this case the page will be accessible from anybody.

Check if useful!

UPDATE

you can create a UserDoctor model connected to User auth mode

```
 class UserDoctor(models.Model): 
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True, blank=True,related_name="user") 
     name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True) 
     surname = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
     ecc...
     temporary = models.BooleanField(default=1)
```

if it becomes definitive put temporary = 0

Comment: This is an appointment app that gives the doctor the ability to create an appointment for register user and non register user. In the first case register user he just selects the patient and create the appointment. But in the case of non register user he needs to create a temporary user, so if the user creates an appointment, he need to be login no matter what type he is

Comment: and how can I make this user automatically a temporary user

Comment: temporary = models.BooleanField(default=1); if become definitive and compile all form update the field to 0 and give other privileges

Comment: so sorry it works, but when I want to query all appointments I have 2 tables, then it will be a little mess is there another way to make a form that allow user to create another temporary user in the same User table